# Spring security - login architecture

Tags: java, rest, spring-security

I have been following the example in this tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/28/the-api-gateway-pattern-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iv

In brief:

1. I have a server called UI that has some html and angular js.
2. I have a server called resource that has a RestController who is serving the content from a DB. All the calls must be authenticated.

The UI server has a login page which works with spring http basic login and creates a spring session that is stored in a Redis server and it is shared to the resource server. When i have some dummy users  in memory authentication everything works fine.

**The question is:**
I want my UI server to be able to perform a login with real users, that exist in the DB. The UI server should not have any DB related code (not knowing its existence) but it should call a REST service in the resource server. The only way i was thinking (but is sounds wrong to me) is to implement a userDetailsService bean in the UI and the loadUserByUsername method should call a rest service from the resource server (e.g. /getUser). The rest service should return all the user details including credentials and roles for the given username. However, to my understanding, this service cannot be secured (for the call to be successful) which compromises the entire security.

I am open to all suggestions and recommendations. Bare in mind this is my first attempt to work with Spring.

Thank you in advance,

Nicolas

Comment: Your **question** actually your answer that implemented in lot of application, beside rest - that id should be hidden without any possibility to track where you have access point.

Comment: **@Appeiron** thanks for your reply. I am not really sure i understood what you are trying to say.. Correct me if i am wrong but you suggest that my "way" of providing an unsecured service that returns a user by username is the way to go as long as i hide this service? That would be fine if I hide the entire resource server from the outside world by enabling only local calls, but i don't want that since a mobile app could also be a possible client.

Comment: It just my opinion as front-end developer to operate `/getUser` method only once at start of application without messing with cookies, ids, storage etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that someone is interested how i tackled this..

I decided to do the prudent thing and study spring security.. :)

My answer is to use a custom **AuthenicationProvider** in my **UI** server, which will call an unprotected rest login service in the **resource** server, which in turn validate the user against the DB.

If the response is successful (e.g. a user object could be returned with username, password, roles) then i will create a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object out of it and return it.

If the response is **NOT** successful (e.g. return object was null or an exception was thrown) then i will either return null or throw an AuthenticationException, it depends on how Spring behaves... I haven't reached that part of studying yet..

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-intro-authentication

Answer (score -1):

Spring Security is a powerful and highly customizable authentication and access-control framework. It is the de-facto standard for securing Spring-based applications.

Spring Security is a framework that focuses on providing both authentication and authorization to Java applications. Like all Spring projects, the real power of Spring Security is found in how easily it can be extended to meet custom requirements

Features
Comprehensive and extensible support for both Authentication and Authorization

Protection against attacks like session fixation, clickjacking, cross site request forgery, etc

Servlet API integration

Optional integration with Spring Web MVC